# LibGDX: Tracking nodes while moving/animate

Tags: java, libgdx, game-engine

does anyone know how to track position of nodes in the ModelInstance while moving/animate?

```
Vector3 moving = new Vector3()
entity.modelInstance.getNode("RightHand").localTransform.getTranslation(moving);
```

it seems like the value is not referenced when modelInstance moves position.

the same results occur when using this code

```
mov = beMainChar.modelInstance.getNode("RightHand").translation
```

thank you in advance

Comment: I mean when entity.modelInstance moves to new position, Vector3 moving values still the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `localTransform` of `RightHand` wouldn't change because the `ModelInstance` is translated to another global positions, for that you need to inspect the `globalTransform` of the `Node`.

```
Vector3 moving = new Vector3();
entity.modelInstance.calculateWorldTransform();
entity.ModelInstance.getNode("RightHand").globalTransform.getTranslation(moving);
```

Comment: thank you, yeah I've tried it, but the moving value hasn't changed, I found docs about node [translation](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g3d/model/Node.html) not modified by animations, so how can I track new node position?

Comment: calculateWorldTransform() not such a method, maybe you mean calculateTransform()..